# Can sponsor remove sponsored subentries?

Tags: trustline

Is it possible to remove a sponsored entry from only the sponsor?

So if I have account A that sponsors a trustline for account B, then can account A remove the sponsor without the signature from account B?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From [CAP 33](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/core/cap-0033.md#why-doesnt-revokesponsorshipop-obey-typical-rules-of-sponsorship):

> The relationship between sponsoring account and sponsored account can
> only be created by mutual agreement. When this relationship is
> established, the sponsoring account is endowed with the right to
> unilaterally end the relationship (ie. revoke the sponsorship) as long
> as doing so will not leave the sponsored account below the reserve
> requirement. But revoking the sponsorship is strictly worse for the
> sponsored account than transferring the sponsorship, because the worst
> thing that the new sponsoring account can do is revoke the
> sponsorship. Therefore, the sponsoring account should be able to
> transfer the sponsorship with the consent of the new sponsoring
> account but unilaterally with respect to the sponsored account.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case (I should have specified) the sponsored account won't have the minimum balance to hold the trust on its own, I was hoping for a way to remove the trust without the sponsored account consent